# blog template don't show markdown files

Tags: templates, material-ui, blogs

I tried to include blog components into standard material-ui-shell(npx create-react-app mui-app --template material-ui)  at home.js and don't see posts! Instead I see

```
 /static/media/blog-post.1.0c315da1f0a7af641a3a.md/...
```

Look at the whole chain:

Im routes.js

```
{path: '/home',exact: true,element: (<AuthorizedRoute><Home /></AuthorizedRoute>),},
```

In home.js

```
const HomePage = () => {const intl = useIntl()
```

```
return (<Page pageTitle={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'home' })}><Typography> <Blog/></Typography></Page>)}export default HomePage
```

In blog.js:

```
import post1 from './blog-post.1.md';import post2 from './blog-post.2.md';import post3 from './blog-post.3.md';
```

```
const posts = [post1, post2, post3];
```

In Main.js

```
function Main(props) {const { posts, title } = props;
```

```
return (...{posts.map((post) => (<Markdown className="markdown" key={post.substring(0, 40)}>{post}</Markdown>))}</Grid>);}
```

In markdown.js

```
...export default function Markdown(props) {return <ReactMarkdown options={options} {...props} />;}
```

Posts output result:

```
/static/media/blog-post.1.0c315da1f0a7af641a3a.md/...
```

how can I solve this problem

I  nothing try to do because I don't understand from were this output path for markdown files!